# Angular formly templateOptions description not showing

Tags: angular, angular-formly

I try to display a description on my formly field but it doesn't appear.

I tried to include the description in the schema and on runtime but in either cases, it won't appear.

Schema.json :

```
{
    "key": "CommentText",
    "type": "input",
    "className": "form-group",
    "templateOptions": {
        "label": "Comment text",
        "required": true,
        "maxLength": 1000,
        "description": "test"
    }
}
```

The purpose is to display the characters countdown for fields with maxlength property. But first I need to display just a basic description.

Answer (score 1):

Min/max length should be done with validators.

```
 validators: [
 ],
  validationMessages: [
    { name: MaxLengthValidator.validatorName, message: MaxLengthValidator.message },
  ],
```

But in my code I created custom input with description in template:

```
<input class="formly-string-input"
       type="text"
       [formControl]="formControl"
       [formlyAttributes]="field"/>
<span *ngIf="field.templateOptions.description" class="form-control-info">{{field.templateOptions.description}}</span>
```

And I think ngx-formly input does not have description to display

[Sourece code of input](https://github.com/ngx-formly/ngx-formly/blob/v5/src/bootstrap/src/lib/types/input.ts)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FieldType } from '@ngx-formly/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'formly-field-input',
  template: `
    <input *ngIf="type !== 'number' else numberTmp" [type]="type" [formControl]="formControl" class="form-control" [formlyAttributes]="field" [class.is-invalid]="showError">
    <ng-template #numberTmp>
      <input type="number" [formControl]="formControl" class="form-control" [formlyAttributes]="field" [class.is-invalid]="showError">
    </ng-template>
  `,
})
export class FormlyFieldInput extends FieldType {
  get type() {
    return this.to.type || 'text';
  }
}
```